# How to depend on targets of a previous make invocation

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a lib (say `mylib`) and two executables and one of these (say `exe1`) depends on lib. In file system i have:

```
src
   Makefile
   ...
   lib
     mylib
       Makefile
       ...
   exe1
     Makefile
     ...
   exe2
     Makefile
     ...
```

and by launching `make` in `src` dir all is builded.

`Makefile` in src:

```
EXE=exe1 exe2
LIB=mylib

all: $(LIB) $(EXE)

.PHONY: $(LIB) $(EXE)

$(LIB):
    $(MAKE) -C lib/$@

$(EXE): $(LIB)
    $(MAKE) -C $@
```

and, for example, `Makefile` for `exe1` is:

```
...
all: exe1 copy

exe1: exe1.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJ) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
...
```

My problem is that if i change a file in `mylib` dir the library is correctly rebuilded but `exe1` obsiously no...is there a way to teel `make` that `exe1` target depends on a target (mylib) that is specified in a previous invocation of `make` without specifing dependencies on `mylib`'s files in `exe1` `Makefile`?

Thank you all.

Comment: I don't think there is a sane way to do this with separate Makefiles.  If you had a single Makefile for your entire project, this should be simple.

Comment: ripleee's comment is probably not the answer you want to hear, but it's true. Look up a paper called "Recursive Make Considered Harmful". Both normal `Makefile`s and automake's `Makefile.am` can both express non-recursive build systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@tripleee and @JackKelly (curse his name) are right, this is not a healthy makefile system.

You can get something like what you want by changing `src/Makefile`:

```
EXE=exe1 exe2
LIB=lib/mylib/mylib

all: $(LIB) $(EXE)

.PHONY: $(EXE)

$(LIB):
    $(MAKE) -C lib/mylib

exe1: $(LIB)

$(EXE):
    $(MAKE) -C $@
```

and changing `exe1/makefile` so that it will *always* rebuild `exe1`:

```
.PHONY: exe1
```

This still has many problems, but at least it will correctly rebuild `lib/mylib/mylib` and `src/exe1/exe1` when you run Make in `src`. (It will **not** work if you run Make in `src/exe1/`.)